# AppRegistry use in React-Native? with examples?

Tags: react-native, documentation

I am going through documentation of [AppRegistry](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry) in React-Native.
Documentation does not have method details or example. I have searched, but did not find examples.

Does anyone have examples for AppRegistry? I am looking for use of all methods.

PS: With one internal (office) framework, I am testing AppRegistry support. In order to achieve that I need to test all methods.

Answer (score 0):

let's refer [in this library](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/packages/docs/src/apis/AppRegistry/AppRegistry.stories.mdx), hope this can help you